Inch amount to ml
Researching about plants I’ve found that the watering amount is mostly given in inches.
As I understand to get the ml amount all I have to do is multiply the cross-sectional area of the flower pot/soil with the height of the water amount in inches. However flower pots are mostly have a bigger cross sectional area at the top than at the bottom. Do I use just use the area of the top, do I used the average area of the whole pot or do I used the average area from the top to the prescribed water depthness (e.g. if I have a flower pot that is 3 inches tall but the prescribed depth of water is only an inch do I just measure the average from the top the inch? )
Thank you.

I wonder if you are overthinking it - just convert inches to mm  - multiply inches by 25.4 for mm.  If its for plants in a pot why not just water it so water starts to drain out the holes in the bottom [ ie i'm positing that for plants in pots with regular drainage holes its self regulating and you don't worry about inches - only frequency between watering and putting in enough water that it soaks through the soil.]    You might want to do a bit of research on  the term "field capacity" (which is not exactly what it sounds like - and explains how water retention in soils works)

@davidgo, I am carrying out some research in the frame of a school work, which is why I do need to exact numbers. I have decided to just take the surface area of the top and multiply that by the height (to get an ml amount), if I do not find a better solution.
Thanks for your help anyway!

@doorenjoyer Your approach is good, but even better would be to use the average of the areas at the top surface and bottom surface of the pot, if the pots you are using are sloped.

@OllieVet Alright, that was the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much! :)
